# How to test a Dockerfile with minimal overhead

Tags: docker

I'm trying to learn how to write a Dockerfile. Currently my strategy is as follows:

1. Guess what commands are correct to write based documentation.
2. Run `sudo docker-compose up --build -d` to build a docker container
3. Wait ~5 minutes for my anaconda packages to install
4. Find that I made a mistake on step 15, and go back to step 1.

Is there a way to interactively enter the commands for a Dockerfile, or to cache the first 14 successful steps so I don't need to rebuild the entire file? I saw something about `docker exec` but it seems that's only for running containers. I also want to try and use the same syntax as I use in the dockerfile (i.e. ENTRYPOINT and ENV) since I'm not sure what the bash equivalent is/if it exists.

Comment: `to cache the first 14 successful steps so I don't need to rebuild the entire file` Docker does have caching, though. Unless you're changing the bottom layer of your image, you shouldn't have to rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: `Is there a way to interactively enter the commands for a Dockerfile,` In general, you can get an interactive shell using `docker run -it <tag> /bin/bash` (Assuming bash is installed inside the container. Some images only have `/bin/sh`.)

Comment: So to use docker run, will I need to make an image that compiles first and use it's name as <tag>, then run the commands that I want on it?

Comment: You don't need an image that compiles. You can use the image hash from the last stage that built successfully. You can use an image hash anywhere you'd use a tag. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098810/530160

Answer (score 1):

you can run docker-compose without the --build flag that way you don't have to rebuild the image every time, although as you are testing the Dockerfile i don't know if you have much options here; the docker should cache automatically the builds but only if there's no changes from the last time that you made a build, and there's no way to build a image interactively, docker doesn't work like that, lastly, the docker exec is just to run commands inside the container that was created from the build.

some references for you: [docker cache](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-build-cache), [docker file best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)